# Add row numbers to CSV

Tags: python, csv, indexing

Say I have this CSV:

```
apple
orange
banana
strawberry
```

How could I make it so that there's always the correct line number to the left of the item and adapt it in the case an item is added or removed from the csv.

Ex:

```
1,apple
2,orange
3,banana
4,strawberry
```

If I remove banana --> strawberry becomes line #3

```
1,apple
2,orange
3,strawberry
```

Then if I add banana:

```
1,apple
2,orange
3,strawberry
4,banana
```

I'm thinking of doing an independent function that initiates at the very end of when the CSV is done being edited. It'll check the file and arrange it on its own after all modifications have been made to the CSV.

Comment: Please show the code you've started with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use enumerate. By default it start with 0.

#### Code (Python3)

```py
    csv_data = {
        'apple',
        'orange',
        'banana',
        'strawberry'
    }
    
    for index, key in enumerate(csv_data, start=1):
        # save to csv file
        print('{}\t{}'.format(index, key))
    
    # remove 'banana'
    print("\nremove 'banana'")
    new_csv_data = {key for index, key in enumerate(csv_data) if key != 'banana'}
    
    for index, val in enumerate(new_csv_data, start=1):
        # save to csv file
        print('{}\t{}'.format(index, val))
    
    # add 'banana'
    print("\nadd 'banana'")
    new_csv_data.add('banana')
   
    for index, val in enumerate(new_csv_data, start=1):
        # save to csv file
        print('{}\t{}'.format(index, val))
```

### Output

> 1    orange
> 2    strawberry
> 3    apple
> 4    banana
>
> remove 'banana'
> 1    orange
> 2    strawberry
> 3    apple
>
> add 'banana'
> 1    orange
> 2    strawberry
> 3    apple
> 4    banana

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('XYZ.csv')
df['row_num'] = df.reset_index().index
#df.to_csv("XYZ_new.csv")
print(df)
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: It works but there's an issue. I removed ['row_num'] (no headers) and changed the 3rd line df.to_csv('XYZ.csv') to overwrite the current CSV file, but now everytime I run the code, it'll add a new index. Also, is there a way to make indexes start at +1? (1,2,3,4...).

Comment: df['row_num'] = df.reset_index().index+1

Comment: I still get a lot of issues. I'll try to look for another way ,thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shooting in the dark here since I can't see your code, but a simple counter could help?

```
with open("fruits.csv", newline="") as fruit_basket:
            fruits = csv.DictReader(fruit_basket, delimiter=";")
            count = 1
            for row in fruits:
                print("{0}. {1}".format(count, row["Name of Fruit"]))
                count += 1
```

Comment: P.S. change the delimiter to whatever it is in your code